# How does this query with HAVING MAX actually works correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, having

I have 2 simple tables: `students(sno,sname,age)` and `take(sno,cno)`. `Take` is the table of a `N-N` relationship between students and courses.
I want to find students NOT taking a specific course.

The following query does the job but it is not clear to me how it works:

```
SELECT s.sno,s.sname,s.age  
FROM students s LEFT JOIN take t  
ON (s.sno = t.sno)  
GROUP BY s.sno,s.sname,s.age  
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN t.cno = 'CS112' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Does it have to do with the order the `MAX` AND `HAVING` are processed?

A trivial way to do this would be with the subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM students  
WHERE sno NOT IN  
(SELECT sno FROM take WHERE cno = 'CS112');
```

But I am interested in understanding the version using `JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

The `CASE` inside the `MAX` yields 1 if they have the course, 0 if they don't. Taking the `MAX` of that `CASE` for each row, yields 1 if the student has any row where it would be 1 (meaning they have the class), and 0 otherwise. By saying they must `HAVING` the `MAX` `> 1`, you're saying they have to have the class. In the most convoluted way possible.

Comment: `Taking the MAX of that CASE for each row`. Row or Group? I can understand vaguely that it does something like that.I am trying to understand the actual steps and intermediate computations

Comment: For each row (pre-`GROUP`), it runs the case. Then, during aggregation, it runs the `MAX` as part of the aggregation, giving the max for each group. At the end, it filters out rows that match the `HAVING` requirement.

Comment: A `CASE` always runs first? How do we know the order?

Comment: It runs pre-aggregation because it's inside an aggregation function (`MAX`). Anything inside an aggregation function (max, sum, count, etc.) will run per-row, and the aggregation function will summarize the results per-group.

Answer (score 1):

This might be easier to understand if you replace the `max()` with a `sum()`.

Consider this `select` statement:

```
SELECT s.sno, s.sname,s.age, SUM(CASE WHEN t.cno = 'CS112' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NumCS112
```

The new column, NumCS112 has the number of times a student has taken the course.  Next, put this in the `having` clause:

```
HAVING NumCS112 = 0
```

Well, this means that the number of times a student has taken the course is 0 -- so the student has not taken the course.

You can do the same thing with `max()`, where you get a flag instead of a count.  So:

```
SELECT s.sno, s.sname,s.age, MAX(CASE WHEN t.cno = 'CS112' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as HasTaken_CS112
. . .
HAVING HasTaken_CS112 = 0
```

However, you don't have the expression in the `select` clause, so you can't use `HasTaken_CS112`.  Instead, you have to use the full expression.

Answer (score 0):

The MAX ensures that if only one of the classes the student is taking is CS112, then it fails the HAVING statement and won't return that student.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the cno filter in the JOIN condition instead of the where, and the look for NULL values in the RIGHT part of the join (indicating a non-match).

```
SELECT s.sno, s.sname, s.age
FROM students s LEFT JOIN take t
ON s.sno = t.sno AND t.cno = 'CS112'
WHERE t.cno IS NULL
```

Since the filter on cno is in the JOIN condition, it will not actually filter out the students (as opposed to a filter in the WHERE clause). In case of a non-match, the Take part of the join will contains NULL, something we then filter on (filtering out the cases where the student did indeed take the course).